# TextView is getting cut off in a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to add two different textviews with different heights like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/single_margin"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/double_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/double_margin"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/single_margin"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newsfeed_ad_title"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="This is example text view that will mess up the height!"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ad_title_text" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newsfeed_ad_info_button"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_rounded_box_light_blue"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/single_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/double_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/double_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/single_margin"
    android:text="Learn More"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
    android:textSize="@dimen/body_text" /> </LinearLayout>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

(Don't mind the drop shadow above. I cropped the image and the shadow is from the actionbar)

The height of the linear layout is determined by the smaller textview instead of the bigger one. Why? And how do I go about fixing it? Thanks in advance

Comment: try to add `android:layout_gravity="fill"` on left textview

Comment: can you please provide your dimen.xml file?

Comment: Your dimen value is different for both textview,

Comment: make your LinearLayout match_parent instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Make textview's height `wrap_content` it will solve the issue

```
android:id="@+id/newsfeed_ad_title"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: can't believe i missed that. that's what i get for coding for hours straight

Answer (score 1):

You want to make the left textview (with ID newsfeed_ad_title) not cut right? Change the android:layout_height to "wrap_content"

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/single_margin"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/double_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/double_margin"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/single_margin"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newsfeed_ad_title"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="This is example text view that will mess up the height!"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ad_title_text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newsfeed_ad_info_button"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_rounded_box_light_blue"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/single_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/double_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/double_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/single_margin"
    android:text="Learn More"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
    android:textSize="@dimen/body_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If this does not solve your problem then give your **dimen.xml file.**

Hope this will be helpful...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `match_parent` `newsfeed_ad_info_button` TextView :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newsfeed_ad_info_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_rounded_box_light_blue"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/single_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/double_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/double_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/single_margin"
    android:text="Learn More"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
    android:textSize="@dimen/body_text" />
```

**Note :** Also use dp instead px :
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first `TextView` (the one with ID `newsfeed_ad_title`) has an height of `match_parent`. This means that first the `LinearLayout` will compute its preferred height, and then the `TextView` will occupy exactly that height.
Giving a `wrap_content` to the first `TextView` will solve the issue, because this way the `LinearLayout` will first ask both children to compute their desired height,and then set his own accordingly.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/newsfeed_ad_title"
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
... //the rest is unmodified
```